# Parallels 8 - will iPhone sync with OS X side and VM side?

Tags: ms-office, parallels-desktop, exchange

I've just purchased a 2012 13" MacBook Air. I hope to run Windows 7 in Parallels 8 to access Office 2010, including Outlook 2010.

Currently, my iPhone syncs to Outlook via a hosted Exchange for mail (and the other stuff it supports), and the sync is seamless. I also sync my iPhone with the Windows version of iTunes (either wired or wirelessly) for music and, again, it syncs well.

My question - will my iPhone continue to sync to Outlook running in the VM *and* be able to sync to iTunes running on the native OS X side? I'd prefer not to have to install iTunes on the Windows side if I don't have to.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you configured itumes

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is yes. My mail syncs with my MS Outlook running in the VM as well as my iPhone and my music syncs via the native iTunes program in my 13 MBA.